# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo webview

Tags: android, webview

seems all things good and my code is correct but when lunch app got this message : Unable to start activity ComponentInfo and give error from this line : `webView.findViewById(R.id.webi);`

this is my Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   public WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);
        webView.findViewById(R.id.webi);
        String sag="google.com";
        webView.loadUrl(sag);
}
}
```

xml layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.erfan.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future, when posting questions to Stack Overflow that involve errors, please post the entire Java stack trace of your crash in the question, rather than forcing us to guess.

In this case, `webView.findViewById(R.id.webi);`  will fail, because `webView` is `null`. Presumably, you want `webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webi);`.

Comment: cant believe do that mistake ... thanks any way . accept your answer in few minute